# nativescript image-cache module not working as per example

Tags: image, caching, nativescript

Using the example provided on the nativescript.org website
I created a page to test the image-cache component.
tns-core-modules/ui/image-cache

The cache.push() works fine.
Any time I use the cache.get(url) the object returns null.  I can never retrieve cached images.

OnComplete of the push it seems the image can be retrieved from cache, but doesn't seem to retain.

This occurs on the emulator as well as the actual connected android device.

I tried creating an empty hellow-world javascript app from scratch 
tns create --template tns-template-hello-world to test the sample and had the same issue.

```
    const cache = new Cache();
cache.placeholder = fromFile("~/images/logo.png");
cache.maxRequests = 5;

// set the placeholder while the desired image is donwloaded
viewModel.set("imageSource", cache.placeholder);

// Enable download while not scrolling
cache.enableDownload();

let cachedImageSource;
const url = "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7392261?v=4";
// Try to read the image from the cache
const image = cache.get(url);

if (image) {
    // If present -- use it.
    cachedImageSource = imageSource.fromNativeSource(image);
    viewModel.set("imageSource", cachedImageSource);
} else {
    // If not present -- request its download + put it in the cache.
    cache.push({
        key: url,
        url: url,
        completed: (image, key) => {
            if (url === key) {
                cachedImageSource = fromNativeSource(image);
                viewModel.set("imageSource", cachedImageSource); // set the downloaded iamge
            }
        }
    });
}

// Disable download while scrolling
cache.disableDownload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `image-cache` module does not have a persistent storage. The images are never written to disk here, it just caches the image on the memory for the current session only, once your app is closed it will loose all the downloaded images.

Or if the queue reaches the maximum memory allocated (that is 1/8 of your device's total memory) then the oldest image on the queue will be marked for garbage collection. In that case if you request for the image again, it will have to be downloaded again.

If I understood right, you are looking to cache the image on persistent storage so it need not to be downloaded again on subsequent app launches. You may do this manually by downloading the image with Http module and write it to a file. We also have a few plugins for the same purpose, [nativescript-web-image-cache](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-web-image-cache) or [nativescript-image-cache-it](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-image-cache-it) are few to name here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I was able to use HTTP and download images locally, then use a listview to display the images using the src="~/localfiles/filename.png".
The problem i am having is when the images are changed and redownloaded with the same filename they are not refreshing in the app unless the app is closed and re-opened. Is there a way to force the images to refresh or a way to clear the cache?

Comment: Just set the image src to null and set it back to new / same path.

Comment: This does not work. It flashes null then displays the cached version of the image.


    for (let i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        listArray[i].src = null;
    }
    
    viewModel.set("myItems", listArray);
    page.getViewById("listView").refresh();

Comment: Sorry, can't say much with a Playground example to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Manoj has stated the image-cache is in memory cache and it is expected to receive null on the initial load. However, once the image is loaded you should be able to retrieve it with no hassle.

For your convenience, I've extracted the cuteness.io test app [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/image-cache-test). In the application, the `image-cache` is used to load thumbnails with placeholders for each item in the listview. You can see on this line that the `cache.get` will return `null` on the initial load but after you scroll the list items down and up the sequential load will return a reference to the native image ([see this line](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/image-cache-test/app/reddit-item-view-model.ts#L61)). Notice that we are not closing the app and that the image-cache is used within the view model to load the `thumbnail` property - in the context of ListView control this would mean that the getter will be triggered each time the cell is rendered (scrolling up and down triggers the recycling and cells are rendered which will trigger the binding).

Comment: Unfortunately I need the images to persist even when the user returns to the app after closing. Is there a method for saving images from a url to the filesystem? Then I could reference the src locally and I would not need to use the cache at all.

Comment: The image-cache is not a bulk save. You will need another plugin or different approach (e.g. saving the images via the file-system and creating an explicit check on consecutive load if the image is already available from the local storage)